# Why is not "a good programming" to throw exception for evreything?

Tags: python, throw

Recently on a project I own, in python and pygame I realise a problem (of hardware) that causes the runtime error of the game. So the game stops on the running. What I did to deal with this problem was to throw all the exception on the commands that casues the error (it is a spesific command).

I don't known what kind of error is that, so i suppose that was a kind of "run-time-error" so to throw exception for a run-time-error, you need to know the string or better the message of the error given by the interpretter. So I avoid this, and I just did a throw exception of the command for any kind of error.

Somewhere I read that this is not so good. But while the game has no user-input (there is a user interaction but is not user-input with the meaning that user doesn't enter number or something like this) why to risk and specify the error as a run-time error, which maybe is not?

So if you have any idea for the above questions, I will be pleasure to get your answer, but my main question is: `Why is not "a good programming" to throw exception for evreything?`

Comment: This is simply not a question. What exactly do you want to have answered? Are you collecting arguments for this opinion?

Comment: @frans:  I disagree, first on principle - if you can have a valid question that indicates, "why is it a bad idea to catch all exceptions", then why is it a bad idea to have a question that says, "why is it a bad idea to throw Exception"?  Second, this question does have a clear and objective answer, as most developers would relate that an exception without context is nightmarish.

Answer (score 3):

The act of throwing an exception indicates, as a developer, that this layer of your application is not fit to deal with the exception.  It **must** be dealt with at some layer higher up.

It is also a good idea to be *as specific as possible* with the kind of error you're getting.  You can't be sure if you're getting a `NameError` or a `ZeroDivisionError`, since they're all going to be `Exception`.  Merely throwing `Exception` tells you as a developer, "Something's wrong....", and isn't specific enough to begin diagnosing.

If you're throwing `Exception`, **stop** and think about why you're doing it.  If you're doing it to pacify some wild runtime edge case, then *fix the edge case instead.*  If you're doing it because the method is making assumptions, then verify your assumptions and be sure that it's caught somewhere else.

If you **must** throw an exception, please be specific as to what the exception is you're throwing.  It will aid you in your debugging and help you in improving the quality of your code.

Comment: I test my application on a pc that for hardware purposes, the game throws an error. So my code is ok, but i want to minimize the possibility to stop. So what I really doing is IF there is an error that stops the game then just avoid this because the error is occure in a not a very importan thing.

Comment: If the error could stop execution of your application, then figure out what it is and fix it.  Merely ignoring it and tearing down the application is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: No, you'd *catch* the exception and not play without any sound.  No sound isn't something that sounds like a show-stopper to this application.

Comment: But it is. My application stops on tha computer with the error that there is no sound card installed or something like this. When I throw exception and don't load music the program runs perfect.

Comment: I don't think you know what throwing an exception is. Raising an extra exception is never going to stop a program from crashing. Quite the opposite.